# what is the apple review guideline for money wallet apps like paytm?

Tags: ios, iphone

I have developed an app like money wallet (e.g. paytm), where user can request money to each other and transfer money to each others account. with every transaction of user, Admin will get some fixed percent commission.

As app is for one small town only,right now user will have to manually contact admin to load money in his wallet or to withdraw it.

I want to submit my app on iTunes store. I know to use any digital content, services, unlock features we need to use In App Purchase. And for any physical good we need to go with any other third party payment gateway.

So I am confused that will apple approve my app or not. Please help.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you never know if Apple will approve or not. The only way to know for sure is to submit and see what happens.

Your description of features sounds like you are probably taking the correct approach.

Its important to use In app purchase for unlocking content/features:

> Apps that unlock or enable additional features or functionality
>   with mechanisms other than the App Store will be rejected

And equally for real world purchases to use something else:

> Apps using IAP to purchase physical goods or goods and services used
>   outside of the App will be rejected

The complete guidelines can be found here https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#purchasing-currencies

And again, its Apples own words:

> This is a living document, and new Apps presenting new questions may
>   result in new rules at any time. Perhaps your App will trigger this.

Comment: so will there be chances to get approved As I am not using In App purchase?

Comment: The main feature you describe "user can request money to each other and transfer money to each others account" is a service outside the app, so you should *not* use IAP for this.

Comment: but we are managing a money wallet inside the app. displaying transaction history and all, so  i am confused.

Comment: It's similar to what any banking app does

Answer (score 2):

I tried to submit using paytm integration sdk, and after that my app got rejected
following is reply from App Store

Guideline 3.1.1 - Business - Payments - In-App Purchase

We noticed that your app or its metadata enables the purchase of content, services, or functionality in the app by means other than the in-app purchase API, which is not appropriate for the App Store.

Next Steps

While the payment system that you have included may conduct the transaction outside of the app, if the purchasable content, functionality, or services are intended to be used in the app, they must be purchased using in-app purchase, within the app - unless it is of the type referenced in guideline 3.1.3 of the App Store Review Guidelines.

Please see attached screenshots for details.

Since your App Store Connect status is Rejected, a new binary will be required.